# Factor w/ 1 level "FALSE"

Tags: r

I have a big data frame with the column df$strand appearing as

`$ strand    : chr  "*" "*" "*" "*" ...`

How can I transform that variable to become:

```
$ strand    : chr  "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
```

I have tried the following, but it changes the variable to "logi"

```
df$strand= df$strand=="+"
```

Result:

```
$ strand    : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you intending to make all of the column into "+"?. If so, assignment is done as `df$strand="+"`.

Comment: If the column has elements other than ' * ', then use `df$strand[df$strand == "*"] <- "+"`

Answer (score -1):

you can solve this by using dplyr package.

```
#install package
library(dplyr)

#Create dataframe: df
id <- c("1","2","3")
strand <- c("*","*","*")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,strand))

df$strand
> [1] "*" "*" "*"


#transform * into +, using ifelse function
df <- df %>%
mutate(strand = ifelse(strand=="*", "+"))
> [1] "+" "+" "+"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why do you transform all elements other than "*" to `NA`?

Comment: You're right! I fixed my answer and specified using NA was to exclude the missing values.

Comment: If `df$strand` has other symbols, e.g. `strand <- c("*","!","-")`, your method not only transforms `'*'` to `'+'`, but also changes `'-'` and `'!'` to missing values. Do you think it's reasonable?